# How to access manually to google sync?

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, sync

I wanna know how can I access my data on google sync. I mean my synced contact, calendar, note data, picasa, people details, chrome bookmarks etc.
please help me with this issue!

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added your Google Account to your phone, do this:

1. Open your device's Settings app .
2. Tap Users & accounts. If you have more than one account on your device, also tap the one you want (if you don't have an account, you can add one tapping `+`).
3. Tap Account sync.
4. Tap More -> Sync now.

Comment: no. you did not get what I mean. the thing you're saying is background sync. I just mean to get my data manually within the interface.  @leonardo-alves-machado

Comment: Well, sorry then, but I really must have misunderstood the question. I recently changed my personal phone, and when I added my Google credentials to it, my data (calendar, notes, photos, etc) was automatically downloaded to the new phone through Google sync... Would you explain with some more details, so I could try to answer what you need?